# Insert radio dial input info into database React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to insert the values of each radio dial into the db 100 meters, 500 meters, 1000 meters. When clicking the submit button it handles the `handleAddProblem` function. It works to add everything except the "difficulty". Do I need to set each radio dial as a different kind of state to achieve what I am wanting?

```
class Submission extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            testUrl: '',
            fileToTest: '',
            difficulty: '',
            name: '',
            instructions: '',
        }
    }

    updateTestFile = (url) => {
        var newUrl= url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'))
        this.setState({testUrl: newUrl})
    }

    handleAddProblem = () => {
        this.props.addProblem(this.state.name, this.state.instructions, this.state.testUrl, this.state.difficulty).then( () => {
            this.setState({name: '', instructions: '', difficulty: ''})
        })
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="background">
                <div>
                  <Header />
                </div>
                <div className="contentContainer">
                  <div>
                    <Nav />
                  </div>
                  <div className="submission">
                    <div>
                      <h1>Submit new problems</h1>
                      <h3>Thanks for helping our site grow</h3>
                      <p> You will need to insert the name, difficulty and instructions for the problem you want to submit. Before clicking on the submit problem button make sure to upload your unit test file first by clicking in the box that says "Click to upload file!". </p>
                      <h4> Be sure to view the unit test example page to see how to write your test file. </h4>
                    </div>

                        <div>
                          <Link to={'/unitTestExample'}><button className="unitTestExampleBtn">Unit test example!!!</button></Link>
                        </div> 

                    <div>
                      <form>
                        <p> Problem name:</p>
                        <input value={this.state.name} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}></input>
                        <p> Difficulty: </p>
                        <input type='radio' value={this.state.difficulty} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ difficulty: e.target.value })}></input>100 Meters<br />
                        <input type='radio' value={this.state.difficulty} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ difficulty: e.target.value })}></input>500 Meters<br />
                        <input type='radio' value={this.state.difficulty} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ difficulty: e.target.value })}></input>1000 Meters<br />
                        <p> Problem Instrctions: </p>
                        <textarea name="description" value={this.state.instructions} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ instructions: e.target.value })}></textarea>
                        <div>
                           <button className="submitButton" onClick={this.handleAddProblem}>Submit Problem</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    <br />

                    </div>

                    <div className="sub-contain">
                      {this.state.testFile ?
                          <div className= 'file-preview dropstyle'>
                              {this.state.testFile}
                          </div> :
                          <AddFile updateTestfile= {this.updateTestFile}/>
                      }
                    </div> 
            </div>
            <div>
              <Stats />
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addProblem }) (Submission)
```

Comment: Have a look at this article that shows how you can handle radio buttons in react: http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out a solution to my issue.

First thing was I changed the difficulty on my `state` to an array like so:

`difficulty: ['100 meters', '500 meters', '1000 meters']`

Then I changed the `value` on each `input` to access the correct index of the array like so:

`value={this.state.difficulty[0]}`

`value={this.state.difficulty[1]}`

`value={this.state.difficulty[2]}`